# Update the header profile picture in header section after uploading the profile on edit profile page in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angularjs-service

I have set the profile pic path on my edit-profile-component.ts file.

Now I want to reflect the same profile path on header section user can see the latest uploaded picture.

```
 public userProfilePicUploadOption: any = {
        url: this.httpClientHelper.serverUrl + '/api/v1/uploadProfilePic',
        fieldName: 'files',
        customHeaders: {'auth-token' : this.authentication.getToken(), 'api-key' : this.httpClientHelper.apiKey},
        filterExtensions: true,
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg']
    };
```

I have create commonService for setter and getter function, this service will called in header and edit-profile component.

Comment: I would set the path as a static injector and inject it into the component that need it. Angular's help docs are very good https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#non-class-dependencies

Comment: Would you like to share some code with us.

Comment: Can we do it by shared services using setter and getter function?

Comment: @Dkouk Can you please check my code while uploading the image.